# Load XML file into oracle database

Tags: xml, oracle, sql-loader

I have XML file content as below

```
<Student id="101">
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Class>6</Class>
</student>
```

I want to load that content into oracle data base including tags also.Help me to clear off this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use CLOB for the data type and QUOTATION for DML operations, thereby I'd keep the formatting and structure of the xml document without having to escape all reserved characters:

Example

```
SQL> create table my_test ( c1 clob );

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test values
    (
     q'[<Student id="101">
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Class>6</Class>
       </student>]'
    );
 
 1 row created

SQL> commit;

SQL> select * from my_test ;

C1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Student id="101">
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Class>6</Class>
</student>
```